# Python beautifulsoup get 2 line of text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie at python. Have tried to learn from scratch ... but need to do something pronto ... which means i havent completed my reading.

**I have the below code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.xxx.co.uk"
page=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lotnav=soup.find(id="lotnav")
address=lotnav.find(class_="col-sm-18").find_all("b")
timeofauction=lotnav.find(class_="col-sm-18").select("span")[1].get_text()

dateofauction=lotnav.find(class_="col-sm-18")
```

**The text inside dateofauction is**

```
XXXX |
14:00,
                        05 December 2017  

                                          63 Mattocke XXX, XXXxxxx, XX1 1XX
```

I am struggling to select "05 December 2017" into a variable. 
Can you please help?

Thanks
Amit

Comment: post the initial html

Comment: is the line breaks in your result relevant and consistent?   if so then split the result on line breaks and get the relevant line.  e.g. `lines = dateofauction.split()` and `result = lines[2]`

Answer (score 0):

If [this](https://www.auctionhouse.co.uk/hertfordshireandwestessex/auction/lot/85993) is the page you're trying to scrape, then can see that the `div` with `class` value of `col-sm-18` contains two `span` tags after which the date appears. The `span` immediately preceding the date contains the time, and since you're already referring to it in your code, you can call the `nextSibling` method on it.

```
lotnav.find(class_="col-sm-18").select("span")[1].nextSibling.strip()
```

That'll give you:

```
05 December 2017
```

**Note:** The `nextSibling` method returns a `NavigableString` object, so you should not call a `get_text()` method on it. It'll raise an error. Simly strip it of whitespace and use it.